# Overwrite data in recording file

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to record a video stream from an ip cam via rtsp. But what if I run out of space on my device? Does ffmpeg have the possibility to overwrite the file? Let's say I set the max file size to 50GB and when the file reaches this limit then the oldest data will be overwritten by the newest in the same file?

Comment: This is impossible. When writing a video stream, you cannot trim old data in the same video file. That's not how a video stream works. You can have the video split to multiple files, and concurrently delete old copies, but that's as best as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment). Example to split the video every 3600 seconds (1 hour) with a maximum of 24 segments before restarting the segment index at 1. Adjust options to fit your needs.

```
ffmpeg -i -i rtsp://user:pass@ip -f segment -segment_time 3600 -segment_wrap 24 -reset_timestamps 1 -b:v 4000k output_%02d.mp4
```

If desired the files can be losslessly concatenated back together with the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat). Refer to the `-segment_list_type` option.

Answer (score 0):

Tape loop -type recording isn't possible with storage devices like HDDs or SSDs. The stream will fill the space and that's that.

What you can do is what **LPChip** suggests, recording in multiple files and deleting old ones when they're not needed. In principle:

1. Start recording `file A`
2. When `file A` is full, start recording `file B`
3. When `file B` is full, copy it to long-term storage with an
   appropriate name like `date_time_file`
4. Rename `file A` to `file B`
5. Loop from 1

Step 3 added just in case there's a need to store the video for a longer period.

How much space you need depends on the quality of the video and the time you want to record. Calculation's easy - bitrate * time. [Here](https://blog.accusonus.com/video-editing/video-bitrate/)'s a good article from Accusonus about video bitrates.